# Driving a servo with 3V efficiently

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, boost

I'm trying to drive a hobby servo operating at 5V with a CR123A 3V battery. The current draw is about 150mA. Is there a way to efficiently boost a CR123A supply to 5V? I've looked at the [LT1615](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/16151fas.pdf), but its efficiency would only be around 77% at 3V Vin. Are there better boost converters out there?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options of high efficiency boost converters. As an example, [MAX8815A](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX8815A.pdf) which you can obtain (in your case) an efficiency up to about 90% in the FPWM mode. Another option is [RT4813A](http://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT4813A/DS4813A-00.pdf) which has an efficiency more than 90%.